# Using Input Values as Query String on Rest API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, input

How do I use HTML input(type: color) as a query string on API

here's my code:

```
const colorPicker = document.getElementById("color_picker");
const color = colorPicker.value;
const url = `https://www.thecolorapi.com/id?hsl=${color}`

  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
<input type="color" id="color_picker" />
```

I tried using the input value as the query string(ID) to generate the color with the input value instead of hand_coding it in Javascript but it's not working.
Please can you help specify a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You're generating your URL by mashing strings together without accounting for the presence of special characters.

A colour code starts with a `#` which is also the character which signals the end of a query string and the start of a fragment id in a URL.

Use [an API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to build your URL instead of string mashing.

```
const colorPicker = document.getElementById("color_picker");
const color = colorPicker.value;
const url = new URL("https://www.thecolorapi.com/id");
url.searchParams.append('hsl', color);
fetch(url).etc.etc…
```

(This also needs to go in a function that you call after a colour has been picked, but I'm assuming you just omitted that part from the question.)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using vanilla Javascript or some framework?

Where are you setting colorPicker?

If you're using vanilla JS then maybe it should be

```
const colorHex = document.getElementById("color_picker").value; //returns a hex color

const colorStr = = colorHex.slice(1) 

const url = `https://www.thecolorapi.com/id?hex=${colorStr}`
```

Comment: The element does not have the id `color`. Your code has all the problems of the original with an extra one.

Comment: So now your code only has the problems that existed in the original code. You still haven't solved the problem.

Comment: Yes I didn't account for the #. Slicing the string should fix this?

Comment: Then the `#` will be missing on the server.

Comment: The color API only requires the hex string without the #. Nevertheless I agree your implementation is much cleaner and better.

edit: grammar.